# wordpress URL 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am experiencing with an error for wordpress, running on window server

WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are pointing to http://www.domain.com/

Permalink Settings is selected as month and name, pointing to www.domain.com/2015/08/sample-post/

ISS Manager Sites is biding to www.domain.com on *:80 (http), path is C:\inetput\wwwroot\wordpress

www.domain.com is able to show the landing page correctly, as well as the list of the post.

www.domain.com/2015/08/hello-world/ (the sample post) is showing 404 error

Is there anything I have set up incorrectly to make this happened?

Would someone please suggest what I shall do to correct this error

Thanks you

Comment: Reset your permalink and see if it works? It seems your .htaccess file is redirecting to 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like none of your permalinks are working at the moment - is this true?

As you're hosting the site on IIS, the usual instructions surrounding permalinks for making sure your .htaccess file is working don't apply to you - they only apply to Apache (and certain compatible servers).

In your case, you need to implement a custom web.config file that tells the web server how to handle the permalinks. A general IIS guide can be found here (http://workfunc.com/how-to-setup-wordpress-permalinks-on-windows-iis/), but as the setup varies slightly between versions of IIS, I'd suggest Googling your specific version of IIS: e.g. "IIS 7.5 wordpress permalinks web.config".

For the sake of completeness of this answer, the web.config file should look something like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hi, by using this is causing the landing page to be 500.. is there anything wrong to do with other configuration?